# I/flutter (22027): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#setData on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
Future<void> _getUserData() async {
  final database = Firestore.instance;
  try {
    FirebaseUser _currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    String authid =_currentUser.uid;
    String email = _currentUser.email;
    Map<String, String> userData = {
      'AuthUserId':'$authid',
      'Email':'$email',
      'FullName': '',
      'MobileNum': '',
      'Address': '',
      'City/Village': '',
      'District': '',
      'State': '',
      'PinCode': '',
    };
   database.collection('UserData').add(userData).catchError((e) {
     print(e);
    });
 } catch (e) {
    print(e);
 }
}
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserData();
  }
```

"I am trying to insert the data into the cloud firestore and i have called this function in initState() but i ham getting error as i have mentioned above

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest `cloud_firestore` version. Then execute:

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
```

---

**Update, Starting since `cloud_firestore` version 0.14.0:**

`setData()` was replaced with `set()`. Other useful link:

[The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the type 'Firestore'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473865/the-getter-instance-isnt-defined-for-the-type-firestore)

Comment: I have the latest cloud_firestrore and I had done the same as you mentioned but after updating the flutter it is happening before it is working fine

Comment: what flutter version are u using?

Comment: Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 27321ebbad (7 weeks ago) • 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
Engine • revision 2994f7e1e6
Tools • Dart 2.7.0

Comment: remove the cloud firestore do packages get and then add it again and do packages get, also close ide and open it again

Comment: unfortunately this is not working, same error again and again

Comment: Did u close the ide?

Comment: @Bawantha add another question with your pubspec.yaml and explaination and add it here in the comment so I can check, also ur build.gradle

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes I restart IDE

Comment: @Bawantha please add another question with build.gradle and pubspec.yaml and link it here

Answer (score 9):

for my case, I performed steps as below:

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
```

*uninstall app*

*update: /android/app/build.gradle*

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

run again.

hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I closed the IDE (Android Studio) and did `flutter clean`. After that I restarted the IDE and created a new AVD. The MissingPluginException was gone after that and I had the following error:

```
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file
```

I fixed this adding `multiDexEnabled true` to the `defaultConfig` in /android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

I don't know if this is releated to your problem, but thats how I solved the error.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was caused by editing the firebase instance settings after I've used the firestore in the previous page which u can't do and it didn't give me the correct error for it until I delete this folder

```
%AppData%\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core_platform_interface-2.0.0
```

and then It correctly gave me the error and so I just applied the settings in main.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) 
{
   return FutureBuilder(
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) 
      {
         if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('error');
         }

         if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(
            persistenceEnabled: true,
            cacheSizeBytes: Settings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
            );

          return MaterialApp(....
         }
      }
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop the running app and rerun. It may be because you added the firestore dependency while the app is already running in debug mode. In this case the hot reload or restart will not work if you to call methods of newly added dependency. You have to stop the running app and rerun. (This solved my issue).

Do this before rerunning.
- flutter clean
- flutter packages get

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Visual Studio Code and you are running your project on an IOS simulator, then it might not work. You can run your project from Xcode and it will work with no issues, you have to open the file that is .xcworkspace.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it helped me

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
```

Later, Uninstall App and try reinstalling it ✌