# Flutter Firestore Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#updateData

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to update a document and keep getting this error:

`ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#updateData on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore`

This is what I am trying to do:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('myCollection').document(documentID).updateData({"fieldName": FieldValue.arrayUnion(newValue)});
```

I am using this versions of Firebase and Firestore

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
```

I tried running `flutter clean` and `flutter packages get` as suggested here: [I/flutter (22027): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#setData on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913165/i-flutter-22027-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-doc). I even tried adding `multiDexEnabled true` to my build.gradle file, as suggested in the same post; none of it worked.

I noticed that my build.gradle file has this flutter versions:

```
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
```

(Don't know if that might have anything to do with the problem)

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error didn't have anything to do with the error message.

The problem was that my variable `newValue` wasn't a list. I solved the problem by changing

```
Firestore.instance.collection('myCollection')
     .document(documentID)
     .updateData({"fieldName": FieldValue.arrayUnion(newValue)});
```

to this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('myCollection')
     .document(documentID)
     .updateData({"fieldName": FieldValue.arrayUnion([newValue])}); //The change is in this line
```