# The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the type 'Firestore'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi guys when i'm trying to declare a instance of Firestore he give this error !
all that's happening after i upgrade my Flutter to last version

[image: screenshot]

> final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

i use

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0
```

Comment: yeah thank you I did't noticeit's New Update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Starting from `cloud_firestore` version 0.14.0:

In the newest version of `cloud_firestore`, the class `Firestore` was deprecated now you have to use `FirebaseFirestore`, so just do:

Import the package:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'
```

To create an instance:

```
final databaseReference  = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

#### Other Links Regarding The Changes on Firebase:

[No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in/63492262#63492262)

[Undefined class 'FirebaseUser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482162/undefined-class-firebaseuser/63482356#63482356)

[cloud_firestore 0.14.0 how to use the data method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63486340/cloud-firestore-0-14-0-how-to-use-the-data-method/63486506#63486506)

Answer (score 4):

**Cloud_firestore version 0.14.0 has the following changes:**
import the package:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

FirebaseUser is not longer available. To declare a Firebase User, use the Following;
//User,

To declare a Firebase instance, use:

```
final firebaseInstance= FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

instead of the calling of .document(uid), use:

```
.doc(uid)
```

for example:

```
    await db
    .collection(Str.USERS_MESSAGE_LIST)
    .document(uid)
    .collection(Str.MESSAGE_COLLECTION)
    .document("$itemId$sellerId")
    .setData({...
```

will become:

```
    await db
    .collection(Str.USERS_MESSAGE_LIST)
    .doc(uid)//note this
    .collection(Str.MESSAGE_COLLECTION)
    .document("$itemId$sellerId")
    .set({//note this
```

Similary for other queries, use of .data() as opposed to .data([]} e.g.

```
.startAfter([lastDocument.data[Str.ITEM_NAME]]).limit(perPage);
```

will re-written as:

```
.startAfter([lastDocument.data()[Str.ITEM_NAME]]).limit(perPage);//note the () after data
```

For a user: use:

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

And many other changes - refer to official Firestore/Firebase documentation