# Is there any way to load image from Firebase to flutter project according to current user UID

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I want to load a image from my Firebase storage. I uploaded images such as profile photos for users with  the name {users uid}.png. So when I go to users profile screen, I want to upload these images from firebase accordingly to the current user uid. What is the best way  for that ?? I have a async method that sets my user properties such as `final loggegInUser`  and I have a async method

```
void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
        print(uid);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

This method sets my global loggedInUser property then I want to load the image from firebase storage like that

```
CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    backgroundImage: FirebaseImage(
                            'gs://homeparty-68792.appspot.com/user_profile_images/${loggedInUser.uid}.png')
                       ,
                   
                    radius: 100,
                  ),
```

But when I load this screen I get

```
ERROR TYPE Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: uid)
```

error. getCurrentUser() methods work properly it prints the e mail and password but in the build Widget It returns null. Why this is happening I need some help ???

Comment: use `bloc`. Put `getCurrentUser` in `initState`.

Comment: You did not show the code, but very likely you do not yet understand how futures work or how to build a widget based on a future result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Where are you calling `getCurrentUser()`?

Comment: I thought other parts of code does not effect the problem I just want to get current user uid and load an image accordingly.But you right I might have some confusions about how futures work.

Comment: @PeterHaddad   I called in state class

Comment: @Xanubra Your problem is that your way to query the authenticated user is *asynchronous*, that means if you want the result, you have to *wait for it*. And you don't. You just rush to the widget building and your result is just not there yet when you build. The duplicate explains that.

Comment: @nvoig Yes I know I should wait that's why I' am asking a solution what is the proper way to doing it how can I wait ? until the image load. Thanks

Comment: The link I posted above explains how to properly use futures and wait for them. Alternatively, the answer you got below gives you an easy way out , because you will be able to get your results synchronously. But sooner or later you will need this anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling `getCurrentUser()` in `initState`, then the problem is that the `build()` is getting called before retrieving the user. Therefore the best thing to do is to upgrade `cloud_firestore` to version `0.14.0` and to add `firebase_core : 0.5.0`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core : ^0.5.0
  firebase_auth : ^0.18.0
  firebase_storage:^4.0.0
  # cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0 not sure if you are using
```

Then you can do the following, first initialize Firebase:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and inside `getCurrentUser()`:

```
void getCurrentUser() {
    try {
      final user =  _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
        print(uid);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

In the new version, getting the `currentUser` isn't asynchronous anymore doesnt require `async/await`.

Some useful links:

[No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in/63492262#63492262)

[Undefined class 'FirebaseUser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482162/undefined-class-firebaseuser/63482356#63482356)

[cloud_firestore 0.14.0 how to use the data method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63486340/cloud-firestore-0-14-0-how-to-use-the-data-method/63486506#63486506)

[The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the type 'Firestore'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473865/the-getter-instance-isnt-defined-for-the-type-firestore/63473889#63473889)

Comment: I get 'Undefined name 'Firebase'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name' which package should I import I couldn't find .

Comment: Did u add firebase_core? `firebase_core : ^0.5.0`

Comment: Yes I added firebase_core : ^0.5.0 in pubspec.yml

Comment: When update my pubspec.yml as your suggestions I get more and more errors ex. I could not use FIrebaseUser anymroe

Comment: Is there any way to wait until the getCurrentUser method complete ???

Comment: Have you read the answer and read the links? You don't have to wait anymore its synchronous

Comment: Ok i did everything as you said but still user.uid return null method.  I create a User user property in State then isnide getCurrentUser i initialize it with _auth.currentUser then in build method I called user.uid.

Comment: is the user loggedin? What do the print statement in the answer return?

Comment: OK i solved thank you soo much now my app working sync it prints the correct user uid. Hovewer bc of I uploaded my pubspec.yml now I can not use FirebaseImage class how can I get images from my firebase with current user uid without FirebaseImage ??

Comment: why cant u use it https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_image/example?

Comment: My fault I can use it so thank you so much for solution I really appreciate You think the question is useful you can vote it.