# Flutter/cloud_firestore: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type Map <String, dynamic> Function()

Tags: function, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, deprecated

I updated my Firestore package and I am getting this error ("**The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type Map <String, dynamic>  Function()**"). I saw that there in another post about the same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63486340/cloud-firestore-0-14-0-how-to-use-the-data-method), but in my case, I am unsure how to make the changes so I am starting a new thread with my code. Can anyone show me how to make the changes, please? The error is showing up in the code below at `List categories = document.data['listCategories'] ?? [];`

```
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _catController,
                            obscureText: false,
                            autocorrect: false,
                            onChanged: (value) {},
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Add a new category here',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    width: 2,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                              ),
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                  Icons.add,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  final String name = _catController.text;
                                  DocumentReference docRef =
                                      userCollection.doc(_uid);
                                  DocumentSnapshot document = await docRef.get();
                                  List categories =
                                      document.data['listCategories'] ?? []; // <-- ERROR 
                                  if (categories.contains(name) == true) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _errorMessage =
                                          '$name has already been added';
                                    });
                                  } else {
                                    userCollection.doc(_uid).update({
                                      'listCategories':
                                          FieldValue.arrayUnion([name])
                                    });
                                    _catController.text = '';
                                    setState(() {
                                      _errorMessage = '';
                                    });
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                            cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            maxLines: 1,
                          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type Map <String, dynamic> Function()` tells you that the object you are trying to do the `[]` operator on is a function. In your case, `.data` is actually not a member variable but a function. It is solved by just adding `()` next to the `data` keyword, so your error line (fixed) would look like that:

`document.data()['listCategories'] ?? [];`

That might've happened because you updated the firebase core package. It used to be just `.data[]` but now it's `.data()[]`.