# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a Flutter application and I have integrated Firebase, but I keep getting this error when I click on a button either to register, login, or logout. I have seen other people have asked the same question, but none seems to work for me. I am using Flutter and [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio). How can I fix this problem?

**This is an excerpt of my code**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            LoginScreen()));
              });
            },
            child: Text("Logout"),
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Below is the thrown exception**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FirebaseException was thrown while handling a gesture:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

#0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:118:5)
#1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:52:41)
#2      FirebaseAuth.instance (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:37:47)
#3      _HomeScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:cosytok/screens/home.dart:20:28)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
#5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:219:7)
#10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:477:9)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:78:12)
#12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:124:9)
#13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
#14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:18)
#15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:108:7)
#16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:220:19)
#17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
#18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
#19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
#20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
#24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
#25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#f0104
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FirebaseException was thrown while handling a gesture:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

Comment: You should now use [Dart-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467105/6618622) way for initializing Firebase.

Comment: I solved it by updating all the packages in pubspec.yaml to the latest version.

Answer (score 847, accepted):

### Starting Since August 17 2020

All Firebase versions have been updated and now you have to call `Firebase.initializeApp()` before using any Firebase product, for example:

First, all Firebase products now depend on `firebase_core` version (0.5.0+), therefore you need to add it in the `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core : ^0.5.0
  # cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0 other firebase dependencies
```

Then you have to call `Firebase.initializeApp()`:

#### First Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Import the firebase_core plugin
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return SomethingWentWrong();
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MyAwesomeApp();
        }

        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return Loading();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

#### Second Example with Firestore:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FirstRoute(title: 'First Route'),
    );
  }
}

class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstRoute({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _FirstRouteState createState() => _FirstRouteState();
}

class _FirstRouteState extends State<FirstRoute> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("test"),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 27,
                    child: Text(
                      "Name: ${snapshot.data.data()['name']}",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
              return Text("No data");
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ));
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc("docID")
        .get();
  }
}
```

#### Third Example:

Initialize it in `initState()` then call `setState()` which will call the `build()` method.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp().whenComplete(() { 
      print("completed");
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

#### Fourth Example:

Initialize it in the `main()` method after calling `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

#### **Note**: You only have to call `initializeApp()` once

Comment: the 4th example should be it. Just remember to add async. I wonder if the delay is noticeable.

Comment: Yup the 4th example is the best one, just thought to show all ways, the second is good also because you can just initialize before getting the first data from firestore or realtime database in the same FutureBuilder

Comment: Thanks, it works using #4. But if you push "back" button, when you go back to the app, it says the same thing "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()" even if it's in main()

Comment: @Octet I just tried it by clicking on the physical back button on a physical device with no issue

Comment: @Octet I just tried this (4th example) on both an emulator and on a physical device and tried what you said. On the emulator it crashes, but on the real device it runs just fine. Weird...

Comment: @AnisR. Very weird indeed, the other options will work on an emulator

Comment: For me it crash on physical device (OnePlus), but not everytimes, sometime it does, sometimes no. I may have an issue on my side

Comment: 4th one is life :) Just curious what does this do `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`

Comment: @MichaelDiCioccio the flutter framework used the widgetbinding to be able to interact with the flutter engine. When you call `ensureInitislized` it creates an instance of the `Widgetbinding` and since `Firebase.initializeApp()` needs to use platform channels to call native then u need to inialize the binding. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html (platform channel are in flutter engine)

Comment: Using a `FutureBuilder` will completely rebuild the widget tree on each hot-reload, so the last one is the best option

Comment: On #1, what can Loading() and SomethingWentWrong() be? If I just stick a Text() in there it complains - "No Directionality widget found"

Comment: #4 Doesn't seem to work with Providers (same error message as initially)

Comment: Until yesterday (Sept 21, 2020) Firebase Messaging worked without Firebase.initializeApp()

Comment: Will getting red screen error for 2 sec then loading properly. How to restrict that red screen?

Comment: NOTE that this may affect in_app_purchase update listener setup, so I think `initializeApp` should be called after. That is only my assumption and I obviously didn't test this (can I even?), so take it with a grain of salt

Comment: Fourth Example will hit E/FirebaseInstanceId( 1584): binding to the service failed but still can work, any idea this error how to fix

Comment: The 4th method doesn't work when using ```flutter_bloc``` does anybody know the best place to call it when using ```flutter_bloc``` i don't want to call it over and over again

Comment: @PeterHaddad 
I'm new to Flutter dev, but a little confused here.  There is a lot of support for the 4th option, but won't that fail if you have no internet connection and crash or lag your app on startup?

It seems like at least with option 3 you can render a loading screen or something and notify the user that you're offline or need a network connection.

I could be mistaken if the `Firebase.initializeApp()` is actually an on-device process.

Comment: Is anyone else getting this exception? FirebaseException ([core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project? 
    
    View the Android Installation documentation for more information: https://firebaseextended.github.io/flutterfire/docs/installation/android
    )

Comment: Note to use "flutter clean" after making these changes and rebuild the app

Comment: what if I don't wanna wait until the app is initialized with `Firebase.initializeApp()` ?? should I always wait as @PeterHaddad mentioned ?

Comment: @JAHelia `initializeApp()` returns a Future that's why `await` is used, meaning that it will take time.. If you want to use any Firebase package then you have to wait until `initializeApp()` is done. If you are using a Firebase package in another page other than `main.dart` then you can use first example if you want should be fine

Comment: @peterHaddad it sounds that I didn't clarify my question, I need to start my flutter app without having to wait for Firebase package to be fully initialized, giving that I use firebase in one of my inner pages (not in main.dart), what I did was I removed the `async` and `await` from `main()` method in the fourth example, but it ended up in a crash that happens sometimes which's related to Firebase app not initiated.

Comment: I am getting the snapshot.hasError() true so what should I do... I had the same problem @PeterHaddad check this out I have created another query for this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68976949/unable-to-use-firebase-initializeapp-getting-snapshot-haserror-for-firebase

Comment: I don't know why but when I try debugging on chrome, browser freezes and VScode is displayed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69218504/debug-chrome-got-freezed-by-firebase-initializeapp

Comment: what if I'm having this problems when running the tests? (app fixed and runs)

Answer (score 194):

1. Add to pubspec.yaml

   ```
   firebase_core :
   ```
2. add to main.dart

   ```
   import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

   void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp());
   }
   ```

Comment: These lines will give: lib/main.dart:6:9: Error: Getter not found: 'Firebase'.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
        ^^^^^^^^

Comment: I forgot to imprt firebase_core. Did that. Now: These lines will give: E/flutter (24294): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Comment: It says here https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android that: The Firebase Android library firebase-core is no longer needed. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.

Now, to use Analytics or a product that recommends the use of Analytics (see table below), you need to explicitly add the Analytics dependency: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0 or com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0.

Comment: What about if initializeApp will crash? Application wil not started. I not found anything about this possibly problem.

Comment: @BorisSalimov Because `initializeApp()` is an async call, the application will still start even if it fails

Comment: @Umuko Yes it is right if we will to use FutureBuilder and exception handling, but using _await_ before _runApp()_ may be cause of problem.

Comment: It's show me a error - The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder: I/flutter ( 5612): The method 'then' was called on null. I/flutter ( 5612): Receiver: null I/flutter ( 5612): Tried calling: then(Closure: (dynamic) => Null)

Comment: Is there a method without using init to run past cloud_firestore versions? 
Otherwise, do I have to update the project that has already been done?

Comment: it Almost works to me! When i put exactly code, i had some errors, then i found that: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initialization

Answer (score 36):

## Dart-only initialization (Recommended)

- ##### Initialize Firebase on all platforms using CLI.
- ##### No need to add any native code.
- ##### No need to download any Google services file.

1. Install FlutterFire CLI

   ```
   dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
   ```
2. (Optional) Add the following line to your `~/.zshrc` file and save it

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
   ```
3. Run the `configure`:

   ```
   flutterfire configure
   ```
4. Press `enter` to configure all the platforms

   [image]
5. You should now have a `lib/firebase_options.dart` file. Import this file in your `main.dart` and use `Firebase.initializeApp`.

   ```dart
   import 'firebase_options.dart';

   void main() async {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

     // This is the last thing you need to add. 
     await Firebase.initializeApp(
       options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
     );

     runApp(...);
   }
   ```

---

### Migrating to Dart-only initialization:

If you already have an existing application, you can migrate it in the following ways.

- #### Android:

  1. Delete `google-services.json` file from `<flutter-project>/android/app`:

     [image]
  2. Delete the following line in `<flutter-project>/android/build.gradle` file

     [image]
  3. Delete the following line in `<flutter-project>/android/app/build.gradle` file

     [image]
- #### iOS

  Open `<flutter-project>/ios/Runner.xcworkspace` file in Xcode and delete the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from the Runner.

  [image]
- #### macOS

  Open `<flutter-project>/macos/Runner.xcworkspace` file in Xcode and delete the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from the Runner.

  [image]

More information can be found [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/)

Comment: This is the only working solution I found, thanks a lot dude! I was using the platform based method and never aware of the new implemention. Once I tried to add Ios app, I fall into this error, by creating a fresh project and following this solved the issue.

Comment: I could not  import 'firebase_options.dart'; and also  DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform is not found. Is there anything to update?

Comment: @SwetaJain Was a `firebase_options.dart` file generated after the 4th step?

Comment: This firebase cli solution is also the best I found. You can find flutter documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: in my case i also had to install firebase-tools to make this work. Anyhow this was the only thing worked for me :). **(27 FEB, 2023)**

Comment: in my case, i had to a few minor things different than CopsOnRoad's answer, but between CopsOnRoad answer and the url @Dorian provided (firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) it fixed my error.

Comment: For me it didint work for flutter web, saddly I've tried with flutterfire cli and manually configure (initializeApp with options provided by cloud messaging) no success at all... :(

Answer (score 20):

If you followed [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in/63492262#63492262) and are still getting the same error, check to make sure anything else you have in your `main` function comes after the `await Firebase.initializeApp()` call, like so:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Since August 2017, all Firebase services have been updated so that you have to call Firebase.initializeApp() in your main before you can use any of the Firebase products, for example:

If you want to use the firebase_core plugin in a flutter application, then in your pubspec.yaml file add the firebase_core as below

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.19.1
```

Then call the Firebase.initializeApp(): in your app. same as something below:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 17):

First, add this dependency:

```
firebase_core :
```

Second: in the project main function, add these two lines and make the function async:

```
void main() async {
    // These two lines
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    //
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now you can use Firebase normally in any file or widget in the project.

The *FutureBuilder* widget will work either, but you must add it every time you want to access Firebase.

Answer (score 11):

[Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63492262/16124033) is *perfect*, but *if* you still get an error in your code and follow the [Flutter Firebase codelab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter), note that those tutorials are outdated as of August 2020 and not updated yet.

**You need to do many other changes like:**

- replace `.data` with `.data()`
- replace `updateData` with `update`

Answer (score 11):

**Since Flutter versions 2.8**, FlutterFire can now be initialized from Dart on all platforms using the Firebase.initializeApp function. There's a more simple and quicker way to initialize a firebase project, instead of downloading the .json and .plist file from the firebase console and placing them into your Flutter project folders which can result in several warnings. This is a problem I've experienced several times and here's how I solved it.

**After creating your project in the firebase console [steps here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#setting_up_a_firebase_project_and_registering_apps) and installed the Firebase CLI [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli), please proceed with the following steps:**

*You can skip step 1 and jump to step 4 if you've already configured your firebase project with flutterfire configure.*

1. From your project root terminal, command:

   ```
     $ flutterfire configure   
       // This requires the Firebase CLI to work.
   ```
2. Select firebase project by hitting return or enter.
3. insert the bundle ID. You can get this by right clicking the ios folder > then click'Open in xcode'. The Bundle Identifier will appear in the right white panel and you'll have to type this in the terminal manually when prompted.

** Proceed to step 5 if you already have the firebase_core plugin installed. **

4. Install the latest version of the firebase_core plugin by running this command from your project root directory:

   ```
    $ flutter pub add firebase_core  // Adds to pubspec.yaml
   ```
5. Add imports to the main file:

   ```
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'; // 
    import 'firebase_options.dart'; // Generated file
   ```
6. Update your main function to initialize firebase with this async function:

   ```
     Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(options: 
      DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
      runApp(const YourAppName());
     }
   ```

[See the FlutterFire documentation for more information.](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire)

Comment: I was missing the 'firebase_options.dart' file to be imported. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I already tried this way and not working for firebase_messaging on fluttter web (ios and android is fine though)

Answer (score 10):

**Flutter Web with Firebase**

If you are using Flutter Web with Firebase make sure you have the SDKs installed in the `body` tag of your `./web/index.html`

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

Furthermore, make sure you call `firebase.initializeApp(...)` with the configuration parameters in the `index.html` as well.

```
  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIz...",
      authDomain: "...",
      databaseURL: "https://<project-name>.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "<project-name>.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "...",
      appId: "...",
      measurementId: "..."
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
```

At last configure firebase as described in [Peter Haddad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in/63492262#63492262):

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: That is not securely put sensitive data inside .html

Comment: @user7856586 what would you say is the sensitive data in this case?

Comment: sorry I mean that we should also fix rules on Gcloud, cause storing naked data in html file is not secure. Look [here](https://medium.com/@devesu/how-to-secure-your-firebase-project-even-when-your-api-key-is-publicly-available-a462a2a58843)

Answer (score 9):

You need to add `await Firebase.initializeApp();` which is a `Future`. Do it inside the dart file that is running your Firebase function like below:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
...

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you still have the problem when you leave the app to the main screen, you could add this to whatever `.dart` file using Firebase:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {

  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Or in the case of a `StatefulWidget`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Import the firebase_core plugin
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  // Set default `_initialized` and `_error` state to false
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;

  // Define an async function to initialize FlutterFire
  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Show error message if initialization failed
    if(_error) {
      return SomethingWentWrong();
    }

    // Show a loader until FlutterFire is initialized
    if (!_initialized) {
      return Loading();
    }

    return MyAwesomeApp();
  }
}
```

For more information, check [this link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initializing-flutterfire).

Comment: I am getting the error even if I do the same procedure as documentation. here is the error `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
` . I already initialized the Firebase in stateful widget.

Answer (score 5):

This is the way to initialize firebase in 2022

First of all, Install FlutterFire with this link ==>
[Flutter Fire Installation Link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/)

After installing FlutterFire, you'll need to add these lines of code in your lib/main.dart file

```
  import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
  import 'firebase_options.dart';
```

Then edit your Main Function as done below

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp(options:                                  
   DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);
 runApp(MyApp()); 
 }
```

This can change in the future, so refer to this link for the latest implementation reference below

[Initializing FlutterFire#](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/)

Comment: Still getting the error.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases this problem is observed after upgrading the project from older Flutter version to null safety. These things should be checked:

Ensure you have firebase-core in pubscpec.yaml

Import firebase core:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
```

Init Firebase before any call - preferably inside main.dart so it is executed before any other implementation:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

From offical [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#:%7E:text=From%20your%20Flutter%20project%20directory%2C%20run%20the%20following%20command%20to%20install,flutter%20run).

Comment: I did this but I still get the same error in the title and I followed the flutter fire config commands .please advise

Comment: All the answers are just repeating the same thing that repeatedly also don't work. Ha!

Comment: Exactly @KhoPhi.... Didn't wor for me as well... (flutter web only, iOS and Android is fine)

Answer (score 4):

**You should call `await Firebase.initializeApp();` before using any Firebase code in your app:**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**Take into account that if you put that line in another method:**

```
Future<void> configure() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // More code...
}
```

**Don't forget to add the `await` clause when calling that method:**

```
void main() async {
  await configure();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**Because the method `runApp` could be called before executing the `await Firebase.initializeApp();` line from the configure method**

---

**Remember to add the `firebase_core: ^2.13.0` package into the `pubspec.yaml` file:**

```
dependencies:
  firebase_core : ^2.13.0
  # firebase_auth: ^4.6.1 or other firebase packages
```

**And import the `firebase_core` package:**

`import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';`

Answer (score 3):

I needed to reconfigure the Firebase app with FlutterFire cli.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli

1. Install firebase-tool via NPM: `npm install -g firebase-tools`
2. Install flutterfire cli: `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`
3. Run this command to configure firebase in your project: `flutterfire configure`

Follow the above link and initialise as follows:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

As its await call, The app will show splash screen and Firebase may not initialise so I proceeded next with another FutureBuilder for `home` screen to make sure Firebase app is initialised before I use FirebaseAuth.

```
home: FutureBuilder(
          future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10));
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return snapshot.hasData ? Home() : AuthPage();
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Text('');
            }
          })
```

Comment: I have updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using the right/official version of the firebase package.

I was using:

```
firebase_core_dart: <version-number>
```

at: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core_dart

instead of the official

`firebase_core: <version-number>`

at https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core

Using the first option, I got the initialized when using:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  ).whenComplete(
      () => print('FIREBASE INITIALIZED================>'));
```

but the authentication failed with the error message described by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize in the **main.dart** file as well like this using **FutureBuilder**.

```
 future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
```

Look at this example.

```
void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
       return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'NEWSAPI.org',
          home: SplashScreen(),
       
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
            SPLASH_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => SplashScreen(),
          },);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66007603/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to comment. But this issue have lot of trails.
For my case.

I was initializing Injection Container Before Firebase.
Hierarchy needs to be check.

```
Hive.init(directory.path);
  await Firebase.initializeApp();// before
  await di.init();
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Flutter Users**

If you've set Firebase correctly, do not forget to add

> `await`

before

> `Firebase.initializeApp();`

That is mainly the problem with that Exception.
And since it's a Future, do this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialise with firebase options

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform).catchError((e){
    print(" Error : ${e.toString()}");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. It will resolve the issue for both IOS and Android.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

    void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: "found in your google service-info.plist",
          appId: "found in your google service-info.plist",
          messagingSenderId: "found in firebase",
          projectId: "found in firebase"),
    );
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you neeed to add `await FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` in main function remember to add await in main function

Answer (score 1):

On my case, I added web support to my **existing** project.
The one thing which solved the issue is,

In the `web/index.html` file

Changing the `verison` of **all the firebase sdk imports** from `9.6.6` to `8.10.0`

Snippet

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app-check.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
 <script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
   ....
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a project in which the firebase_core was preconfigured and then you are trying to add new packages it will give that error.

You have to first remove `firebase_core:` from pubsec.yaml and then save the file and reconfigure it through `flutter pub add firebase_core` and then `flutterfire configure`.

Then you can add any new packages.

Comment: Nope. I started a fresh blank project, and the error is still throwing up

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I resolved this issue by adding the Google services plugin in

android/app/build.gradle.

**apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'**

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because for the Web version you have to manually add stuff in the *index.html* file, not only the .js dependency, but the configuration. See *[Web Installation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web)*.

We tend to forget that for most stuff Flutter is compiled to the target without the need to change anything target-specific, but in this case one must add the configuration for each target.

Answer (score 0):

Use This for flutter :

```
   const firebaseConfig = {

    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
    };
   
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.getAnalytics(app);
```

Instead of this

```
   const firebaseConfig = {

    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize with firebase options like this:

```
void main() async{
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform).catchError((e){
  print(" Error : ${e.toString()}");
});
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).