# Flutter Firebase dependencies and services

Tags: firebase, flutter

Hi there I have an issue in this code. Where I should place the firebase initializing and crashlytics enabled?

From here SplashPage dart I am getting confuse on how I place the firebase. At the same time if this is correct that what I am doing for this

````
    

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onComplete;
  SplashPage({Key key, this.onComplete}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashPageState createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _initialize();
  }


  _initialize() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    /// Initialize all app dependencies
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    debugPrint('Firebase initialized...');

    /// initialize Firebase and related services

    FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
    debugPrint('Firebase Crashlytics flutter errors enabled...');

    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    debugPrint('Firebase Crashlytics collection enabled...');


    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      widget.onComplete();
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}```**strong text**
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app not initializing Firebase instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198891/flutter-app-not-initializing-firebase-instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting it in void main

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // await
  runApp(/*...*/);
}
```