# Error "[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()" is thrown

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a main file which returns home page and on the home page I am trying to call a new file (`test.dart`). Now the problem is this `test.dart` file is throwing some errors which I am unable to solve as I am completely new to flutter and Firebase Firestore.
Here is the code for `test.dart`:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
// import 'package:vola1/colors.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('countries')
          .doc('nW9L4LGpn2MZVyiTyUII')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data.. please wait..');
        return Container();
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

This is the error it is throwing

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following FirebaseException was thrown building test(dirty):
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  test file:///D:/flutter%20course/vola1/lib/home.dart:88:49
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:122:5)
#1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:54:41)
#2      FirebaseFirestore.instance (package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart:40:21)
#3      test.build (package:vola1/test.dart:15:33)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4569:28)
...
====================================================================================================
```

main file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

home page where the button is calling test.dart

```
ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => test(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Firebase App '\[DEFAULT\]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before using Firebase, you have to call Firebase.initializeApp(); You could do it like this:

```
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: where do await Firebase.initializeApp(); as the main file is some place else            `    
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}           `

Comment: you could write it right after void main, but since it is a future you will also have to await it, so make main async `void main() async{ await Firebase.initializeApp(); runApp(MyApp());}`

Comment: i just updated the code could you please chech it once

Comment: I don't see you calling `await Firebase.initializeApp(); `anywhere

Comment: Do it ABOVE the runApp(); `void main() async { await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}`

Comment: now it is working thank you

Comment: also now there is a new error , i understand if you don`t wanna help!                                  Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: documents

Comment: Perhaps you should post another question, plus this is getting pretty long, I think there is a chat functionality in stackoverflow, but I am not sure if it is  available to new users.

Comment: the chat option isn`t working either... so I guess it is not available for me yet