# flutter web: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in FlutterFire

Tags: firebase, flutter

After searching tons of SO answers also I wasn't able to solve this.

I tried all 4 methods of [No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but, couldn't solve the bug.

I tried adding Firebase.initializeApp() on initState() but, it also didn't work.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:dashboard/app.dart';
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(App());
}
```

**app.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:dashboard/routes/help_and_support.dart';
import 'package:dashboard/routes/homepage.dart';
import 'package:dashboard/routes/items.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'vipatra',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/items': (context) => ShowItems(),
        '/help-and-support': (context) => HelpAndSupport(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**homepage.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:dashboard/style.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('vipatra'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text(
                '',
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.inventory,
              ),
              title: Text('Items'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/items');
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.reorder,
              ),
              title: Text('All Transactions'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app.
                // ...
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.help_outline,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Help & Support',
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/help-and-support');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: 800,
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 15,
                    vertical: 10,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Items',
                    style: headerTextStyle,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 25,
                  ),
                  child: Items(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String? uid;
  late List<Map<String, String>> items;

  Future<String?> getUserId() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
      String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;
      print(uid);
      return uid;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  void getItems() async {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    db
        .collection('biz')
        .doc('demo')
        .collection('items')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        items.add({
          'name': doc.data()['item']['name'],
          'price': doc.data()['item']['price'],
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

class Items extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ItemsState createState() => _ItemsState();
}

class _ItemsState extends State<Items> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> items = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('biz')
        .doc('biz-id')
        .collection('items');

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: items.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> document =
                snapshot.data!.docs[index];
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                leading: Text(
                  document.data()!['item']['name'],
                ),
                title: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        '₹ ${document.data()!['item']['price'].toString()}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: dashboard
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none"

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^6.0.4
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0
  firebase_core: ^1.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Error I am getting:

```
The following FirebaseException was thrown building Items(dirty, state: _ItemsState#ce219):
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Items file:///C:/Users/vignesh/vipatra/dashboard/lib/routes/homepage.dart:90:26      

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:122:5)
#1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:54:41)
#2      FirebaseFirestore.instance (package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart:27:21)  
#3      _ItemsState.build (package:dashboard/routes/homepage.dart:142:73)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)     
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
#8      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4553:5)
#9      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4737:11)
#10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4548:5)     
...     Normal element mounting (10 frames)
#20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)     
#21     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6221:36)
#22     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6232:32)
...     Normal element mounting (109 frames)
#131    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)     
#132    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6221:36)
#133    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6232:32)
...     Normal element mounting (238 frames)
#371    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)     
#372    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6221:36)
#373    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6232:32)
...     Normal element mounting (360 frames)
#733    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)     
#734    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3360:20)       
#735    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1189:16)
#736    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1167:5)
#737    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1181:7)
#738    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
#739    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2582:33)     
#740    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1106:19)
#741    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:328:5)
#742    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#743    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#744    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:973:9)
#747    TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:71:41)    
#748    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:960:27)
#749    WidgetTester.pumpWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:534:22)
#752    TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:71:41)    
#753    WidgetTester.pumpWidget (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:531:27)   
#754    main.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Users/vignesh/vipatra/dashboard/test/widget_test.dart:6:18)
#755    main.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Users/vignesh/vipatra/dashboard/test/widget_test.dart:5:28)
#756    testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:156:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 5 frames from dart:async and package:stack_trace)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
00:04 +0 -1: Demo test [E]
  Test failed. See exception logs above.
  The test description was: Demo test

00:05 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add your pubspec.yaml to the post as well?

Comment: Sure, I added now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this,

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(App());
}
```

Try the below code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

See if it works. Let us know if it worked.

Comment: No. It didn't work. I think the problem is with stream builder.