# Even after using Firebase.Initialize ,method, the error I am getting is No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: flutter

[image]

I followed every step mentioned in firebase and also used the method
Firebase.initializeApp(). Am I missing something because of which I am still getting
this error?

Comment: Did you add google-service.json file to project folders and as well as other configurations?

Comment: @Yohan Malshika Yes all those set up done.......when I try to debug in android emulator I get error failed connecting to service protocol and in web chrome I get that error of not initiliazing firebase

Comment: Hi, did you try to add .then and .catch instead of whenComplete? do you get any error?

Comment: Yes I tried using . initialize ().then((runApp......still the same error.....don't know where I am doing wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Firebase App '\[DEFAULT\]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in)