# Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, web, platform

I want build app flutter on web but I get error when I run

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

error

```
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:5334:11)
at Function._operatingSystem (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:56144:17)
at Function.get operatingSystem [as operatingSystem] (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:56190:27)
at get _operatingSystem (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:56103:27)
at Function.desc.get [as _operatingSystem] (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:5839:17)
at Function.get operatingSystem [as operatingSystem] (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:56056:26)
at main$ (http://localhost:55259/packages/doxaspc/main.dart.lib.js:205:48)
at main$.next (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:39032:33
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:38889:58)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:33875:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:34435:49)
at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:34473:17)
at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:34315:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:34338:35)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:39176:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:39182:13)
at http://localhost:55259/dart_sdk.js:34689:9
```

function main of me

```
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I have build a app android and it work good. but when I want anable web see error above

please show me how fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with a mobile flutter app to configure in Web.

It was because some packages are available only for Android and IOS, and not for the Web.

Maybe you should replace your packages with an equivalent available for all platforms.

Answer (score -1):

`FlutterFire` plugins for web may still be errorneous

Please follow the guide as suggested [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web)

Comment: please help me see error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68548921/error-xmlhttprequest-when-call-api-on-web-flutter