# Where to add Firebase.initializeApp in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Error : no firebase app has been created call firebase.initializeapp
My Question : Where should i need to add firebase initialization

A stateless widget with firestore reference 'users'

```
class FeedBack extends StatelessWidget {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  late String txtnote;
  late String note;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
```

onpress integration for writing data to firestore

```
child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await users.add({
                        'subject': note,
                        'email': 'example@gmail.com',
                        'description': txtnote
                      }).then((value) => print('Data Added Successfully!'));
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Submit',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
```

Note : This dart file 'feedback.dart' does not contain void main function its a stateless widget

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Firebase App '\[DEFAULT\]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in)

Answer (score 8):

You can call inside the main entry point of your app:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

As a default, this should go in the main.dart file

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).