# flutter: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() Other responses are not helping me out

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I tried using an answer to the same question but I am not sure what else I have to do in my case

```
import 'package:auduo/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:auduo/opening_Screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: AppRoutes.define(),
      home: OpeningScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need to see other **.dart** files

Below is the Requested Code From The Comments

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auduo/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
// Bleyl Dev Vid 2 - 7:49

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterViewState createState() => _RegisterViewState();
}

class _RegisterViewState extends State<Register> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _repasswordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mq = MediaQuery.of(context);

    final logo = Image.asset(
      "assets/Auduo Logo V 1.0.png",
      height: mq.size.height / 4,
    );

    final usernameField = TextFormField(
      controller: _usernameController,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
        hintText: "NiceSound259",
        labelText: "Username",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );

    final emailField = TextFormField(
      controller: _emailController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
        hintText: "Something@example.com",
        labelText: "Email",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );

    final passwordField = TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      controller: _passwordController,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
        hintText: "password",
        labelText: "Password",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );

    final repasswordField = TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      controller: _repasswordController,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
        hintText: "re-enter password",
        labelText: "Re-Enter Password",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );

    final fields = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          usernameField,
          emailField,
          passwordField,
          repasswordField
        ],
      ),
    );

    final registerButton = Material(
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: mq.size.width / 1.2,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 15),
        child: Text(
          "Register",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            User user =
                (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _emailController.text,
              password: _passwordController.text,
            )) as User;
            if (user != null) {
              user.updateDisplayName(_usernameController.text);
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.home);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
            _usernameController.text = "";
            _passwordController.text = "";
            _repasswordController.text = "";
            _emailController.text = "";
            //TODO alert dialog with error
          }
        },
      ),
    );

    final bottom = Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        //loginButton,
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Already have an account?",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1?.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.authLogin);
              },
              child: Text(
                "Sign In",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1?.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(36),
          child: Container(
            height: mq.size.height,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                logo,
                fields,
                registerButton,
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
                  child: bottom,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Above is the Requested Code From The Comments,
This is the register.dart code the functions are pretty similar to login.dart so hopefully this is enough.

Comment: Maybe we can start from here, I presume you created the app in your firebase and added the generated file from there to your android folder yes?

Comment: Yes I followed the firebase setup for ios and android. Are you talking about the info.plist or something else. Btw am using visual studio

Comment: Which platform are you developing for? Android or iOS?

Comment: Both but i primarily run the app on the ios emulator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Firebase App '\[DEFAULT\]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in)

Comment: It Worked! but now i get a new error:

Comment: flutter: type 'UserCredential' is not a subtype of type 'User' in type cast

Comment: There's somewhere in your code where you have something like this or closely similar, final currentUser = Firebese.instance.currentUser!; . Share that screenshot or code

Comment: I updated the code above to include the code you were asking for (I Put It In A MaterialButton)

Comment: @O'neya What should I replace Firebase.instance.currentUser with?

Comment: Share the code. That part is just fine. The error could be emanating from how you use it. But I'll need to see your code to pick it out. Edit your original post to include it or just add it as a new a new post below your original

Comment: Code has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` and run the app again. another known fix would be to add the optional parameters `name` and `options` to the

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(name: ....., options: .....)
```

You could also try to minimally reproduce the error by creating the default counter app, add firebase initializations and see if the error persists.