# Flutter - No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created after WatchOS companion app added

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, apple-watch

I have a Flutter app which uses several Firebase services. It worked fine until I added an Apple Watch extension. Since then it throws `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()`.

I have three different build configs so I use a script to copy the proper `Google-Service-Info.plist` file. The script is added via Xcode -> MyTarget -> Build Phases -> Run Script.
The file is copied properly in buildtime. If I switch branch (with no Watch app) it works fine. So I'm quite sure the Watch app caused the issue.

I definitely call `Firebase.initializeApp()` at the beginning of the `main` function of the Flutter app like this:

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
 // ... other stuff ...
}
```

Anyone else faced this issue? What am I missing?

Comment: I think this question will help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/71988835/12902996

Comment: OMG I cleaned up my `AppDelegate` a little bit and managed to delete the `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)` call..........