# Error when initializing Firebase in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

how can i solve this error with Platform exception, i tried to add firebase_core_performance and to run flutter clean and flutter run, but it didn't help

Comment: did you linked your project to firebase

Answer (score 0):

it says `no firebase app has been created`. Run this `flutterfire configure` to your terminal and choose your firebase project. if you haven't created one, choose `new`

Answer (score 0):

it's caused by not adding `firebase core in pubspec.yml` maybe you can see a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in)