# Flutter Web, Flutter Firebase Authentication issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

Running the flutter app on the web I'm getting an exception **only when the login is successful**, when the the credentials are wrong the firebase_auth check works properly returning check validation that (Incorrect email address or password, please try again).

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Query#observe on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:5333:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:18539/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:954:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:39031:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:38888:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:33874:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:34434:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:34472:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:34314:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:34337:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:39175:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:39181:13)
    at http://localhost:18539/dart_sdk.js:34688:9
```

So far I've tried the solutions here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13971 , [I/flutter (22027): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#setData on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913165/i-flutter-22027-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-doc) running

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
```

Also deleting the file

> pubspec.lock

And running `flutter packages get`

***This issue occurs only when flutter app is running on the web, on android and iOS devices it runs correctly***

Also try to add the `firebase_auth_web` and `firebase_storage_web`

```
Flutter 2.0.4 • channel stable 
Framework • revision b1395592de (3 weeks ago) • 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
Engine • revision 2dce47073a
Tools • Dart 2.12.2

  # Firebase dependencies
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_database: ^4.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
  firebase_storage_web:
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

Comment: Interesting, could you upgrade to 2.0.5 and check if the error is still present ?

Comment: @4amvim, Just upgrade and faced the same issue still

Comment: very interesting! could you share a sample project that I could reproduce the issue with ? I'll take a deep look